# How to remove or deactivate the default apache2 server on Snow Leopard?

Tags: apache2, osx-snow-leopard, xampp, uninstallation

I want to install XAMPP on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.6.6).  XAMPP installs apache2, MySQL and some other things.  Since it installs apache2, I need to either be able to remove the apache2 installation that comes installed on OS X, or deactivate it so XAMPP can install it's version.  Can anyone help me out with this?  I'd be extremely grateful.
Peter V.

Answer (score 0):

copy XAMPP to the applications directory, then open up system preferences, go to the sharing pane, and then uncheck the box next to web sharing. start the xampp control panel, and start xampp, open a browser to local host, if you can see that its working.